# How does Hyperleger fabric auto-generate angular app and Rest api for you based on the network created by simply using some commands?

Tags: angular, rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

note that this is regarding the hyperledger blockchain framework

With reference to [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html) tutorial

Refer **Step 5(Generating a REST server) and Step 6(Generating an application)**

I wanted to know how these steps when executed, how files for REST Api and Angular app are generated based on newtork we define in **Step 2(Defining a business network)**

Is there anything used there to generate code for angular app based on block chain network??

Comment: Don't just refer to a link, include some relevant text for future readers in case the link goes down. Even contributors prefer to find all the required information in your post instead of navigating to different links to first figure out what you are talking about.

Comment: The links are from their official site

Comment: Pramit - the information is easy to find - Yeoman generator : https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-hyperledger-composer and REST API generation https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/getting-started-rest-api - once you've generated your REST APIs (for a business network) you can review the Swagger definitions at  the spec at localhost:3000/explorer/swagger.json . Note that LoopBack generates the Swagger for the Composer REST server (from the LoopBack model created).

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Thanks. that is what i was looking for ..:)